Ежесекундное обновление значения в таблице mysql
Делаю простую игру браузерную
Таблица MySQL выглядит примерно так:
Nickname    hp_current     hp_max

Нужно чтобы для каждого никнейма шла проверка if hp_current > hp_max
И ежесекундно добавлялось по 1 единице пока не будет hp_current == hp_max
Этот код реализован, но:
Столкнулся с проблемой, что страница в браузере виснет и ничего невозможно сделать пока равенство не будет выполнено (то есть пока функция не отработает свой цикл и пока равенство не будет "true")
Соответсвенно, если масштабировать проект, подключений может быть больше чем 1 (я),и одновременно нужно будет пополнять здоровье десяткам игроков.
Как это реализовать?

CREATE EVENT

Надо вообще не так делать, а хранить время и пересчитывать при необходимости.

Не нужно считать каждую секунду. На следующий запрос считаете сколько времени прошло и добавляете столько, сколько добавлялось за это время. Токенбакет алгоритм устроен подобным образом.

Это же гениально, спасибо !
